# Как определить, какой пункт контекстного меню был нажат в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-7, freepascal, delphi-xe5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение в среде Delphi. Для его запуска использую два пункта контекстного меню, которые добавляю через реестр. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы приложение различало, какой из двух пунктов был нажат?

Comment: Так у каждого есть номер в коллекции Items.

Comment: параметры командной строки разные передать

Comment: Можно использовать поле `tag`.

Comment: На данный момент, в реестре у меня записан такой параметр                          
`"C:\Проект\Моя программа.exe" "%1"` Т.е по нажатию на любой из пунктов, открывается мое приложение, но какой именно пункт нажат, я не знаю как определить. Как эту информацию извлечь?

Comment: @becouse вы понимаете, что это системное меню винды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам необходимо, чтобы в одном случае, у вас программа запускалась строкой `my.exe file.txt` а  во втором `my.exe file.txt /param` или что-то подобное.
Строка запуска должна различаться, и на основании этих входных параметров при запуске вы уже сможете сделать вывод, что именно было нажато. Есть функции `paramCount` которые вернут число парметров командной строки, это будет 2 и 3  (само имя программы - нулевой параметр) для описанных случаев. И `paramStr()` которая возвращает сами параметры.  Но вы, вероятно, об этом и так знаете, так как должны получать это свое имя файла переданное в `%1`.

Так что вероятно вам надо в реестре запись для второго пункта заменить на какую-то вида `%1 /second`. А в программе уже проверить, например, что число параметров равно трем и третий равен `/second`.
Далее при необходимости вы уже можете привелекать различные функции для парсинга непосредственно параметров командной строки, которые в RTL также имеются.